# How to render fullcalendar events 1 day at a time

Tags: asp.net-core, fullcalendar

We are using fullcalendar in an ASP.NET Core app.

Currently, when we display a month of data, we render the data like this.

```
events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    axios.get(urlString)
        .then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data        //Contains the full month of data events
            successCallback(data);
        })
}
```

However, the data can take up to 10 seconds to return from our controller. Then the calendar renders each day at the same time. This makes our users look at a blank calendar until everything renders at once.

Is it possible to render each day individually? In a loop? That way the user sees day1 render, then day2 render, etc...

If I try putting the above axios in a loop "async() await", the data is retrieve 1 day at a time, but the callback is only called the first time.

Is there a way to render each day individually?

Comment: Hi @Jerry, could you pls share your api? How many records in your database?

Comment: How many events are you trying to display at once? 10 seconds sounds like an awfully long time to wait (for what is presumably a fairly straightforward SQL query?) ...are you sure your server-side code doesn't need optimising? There's no way around this in fullCalendar, except to start the calendar in a single-day view instead of month view - but if the user then switches to the month view, it will try to fetch the whole month of data anyway.